# How can I move a <div> continuously at every given time-interval?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

This is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="a">BELLA</div>

    <script type ="text/javascript">
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("a");
    var myVar = setInterval(spostaDiv, 1000);
        function spostaDiv () {

            myDiv.style.marginLeft = "+10px";

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the div moves only ONE time. Why it isn't running continuosly ?

Comment: +10px is not doing what you think it does....

Comment: you have to use position instead of margin to move a div and "+10px" will not add margin every time you run the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to increment margin value to move div like this -

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("a");
var myVar = setInterval(spostaDiv, 1000);
var margin = 0;

function spostaDiv() {
  margin += 10;
  myDiv.style.marginLeft = margin + "px";
}
```

```html
<div id="a">BELLA</div>
```

Comment: thx a lot, it actually works. I didn't understand well why is not working my code anyway, in theory setInterval(), runs the function given again and again...

Comment: @Maverick yes you're right about `setInterval` function, but again and again you are setting same margin from same reference point.

Comment: Thx, I have understood.